# React-native language and directions with i18next

Tags: android, ios, react-native, i18next, asyncstorage

I'm new to react-native so before asking my question, I would like to know the best option to change language and direction for the whole app! I will be thankful

Now I gave it a try and I set i18n file like this:

```
 `    
 const ns = Object.keys(Object.values(resources)[0]);
 export const defaultNS = ns[0];

 AsyncStorage.getItem('language', (error, language) => {
   i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
     ns,
     defaultNS,
     resources: {
       ...Object.entries(resources).reduce(
         (acc, [key, value]) => ({
           ...acc,
         [key]: value,
       }),
       {},
      ),
     },
     lng: language || 'ar', // my conception is to change the lang whenever the user change it
     fallbackLng: 'ar',
     interpolation: {
       escapeValue: false,
     },
     compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
   });
 });
```

`

here is the function where the user change language

```
`    
//! on press to select language
const handleLanguageSelect = (key: LangProps) => {
  setLanguage(key);
  AsyncStorage.setItem('language', key as string);
  if (key && i18n) {
    i18n.changeLanguage(key).then(() => {
      i18n.language === 'ar'
        ? I18nManager.forceRTL(true)
        : I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
      RNRestart.Restart();
    });
  }
};
`
```

So as I said I'm trying to change the **lng** property whenever the user change the language, but I got error because i18n cannot load on first render because I'm using promise to bring data from asyncStorage...

I expect to get a clear answer of how can i add language and direction support in my react app

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing i18n outside the component.

Here is an example:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      greeting: 'Hello',
    },
  },
  ar: {
    translation: {
      greeting: 'مرحبا',
    },
  },
};

const ns = Object.keys(Object.values(resources)[0]);
export const defaultNS = ns[0];

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  ns,
  defaultNS,
  resources,
  lng: 'ar',
  fallbackLng: 'ar',
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
});

async function changeLanguage(lang: string) {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('language', lang);
  await i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
  if (lang === 'ar') {
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
  } else {
    I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
  }
}

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getLanguage() {
      const lang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
      setLanguage(lang || 'ar');
      await changeLanguage(lang || 'ar');
    }
    getLanguage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{i18n.t('translation:greeting')}</Text>
      <Button title="English" onPress={() => changeLanguage('en')} />
      <Button title="Arabic" onPress={() => changeLanguage('ar')} />
    </View>
  );
}
```